# Iterate over rows in Pandas and apply a function if two columns are equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'ID':"a", 'start':100, 'end': 200}, {'ID':"b", 'start':250, 'end': 300},
 {'ID':"c", 'start':300, 'end': 300}, {'ID':"d", 'start':350, 'end': 500},
 {'ID':"e", 'start':600, 'end': 600}, {'ID':"f", 'start':700, 'end': 900}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
df[['ID','start','end']]



ID  start   end
0   a   100 200
1   b   250 290
2   c   300 300
3   d   350 500
4   e   600 600
5   f   700 900
```

I'd like to iterate over rows of my df and apply a function where the start point and end point columns are equal (i.e. rows 2 & 4), so that I could have a mutated df as below:

```
ID  start   end
0   a   100 200
1   b   250 390
2   c   391 300
3   d   350 500
4   e   501 600
5   f   700 900
```

In the mutated df, where start and end values where equal, I replaced the start value with the end value from previous column+1.

I tried to iterate through rows like this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if(df['start'][i]==df['end'][i]):
      df[start'][i]=(df['end'][i-1]+1) # Here I am trying to refer to the end value in the previous row!
  else:
      df['start'][i]==df[start'][i] # Don't mess with the values if start and end are different!
```

I'd be grateful for any hint/advice on how to resolve this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not iterate rows for vectorisable calculations.

This is one way you can implement your logic via `pd.DataFrame.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['start'] == df['end'], 'start'] = df['end'].shift(1) + 1

#   ID  end  start
# 0  a  200  100.0
# 1  b  300  250.0
# 2  c  300  301.0
# 3  d  500  350.0
# 4  e  600  501.0
# 5  f  900  700.0
```